# Gender of старому in "Им хотелось жить по-старому"

Tags: грамматика, род

In "Им хотелось жить по-старому", is старому in masculine or neuter gender? Why?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: @Cubius my approach to learning Russian is to go through a list of sentences and understand every component. I assumed старому was a declension of старый, and so the question of its gender was interesting to me. If I understand why it's masculine, or why it's neuter - or maybe it's not a declension of старый - then I will have learned something deeper about Russian grammar that extends beyond this specific example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***По-старому - наречие,*** у него нет мужского, женского и среднего рода.

Наречия — ***неизменяемые слова***: они не склоняются и не спрягаются, не имеют окончаний, ***не изменяются по родам*** и числам.

Comment: Тем не менее оно когда-то произошло от предлога **по** и прилагательного, вопрос о роде которого вполне осмыслен.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably neuter. Nounless adjectives used abstractly or referentially take the neuter singular in Russian. (Can't think of the exact term for such usage; what I'm talking about is those cases where Spanish would use *lo*+masculine, and Latin/Ancient Greek/Church Slavonic would use the neuter plural, if that's any help. E.g. **Лучшее — враг хорошего** "Better things are enemies of good things.") However, at this point **по-старому** is, like the previous answerer said, an adverb, and the exact etymology of adverbs is of little relevance. Just how little is demonstrated by the curious fact that the adverb **по-русски** is technically malformed, being a very old contamination of *русски* and *по-русскому* (or the archaic *по-русску*).

Comment: Would you say that "in the old ways" is an accurate translation of по-старому?